# How to include SSL certificate files in HTTPS request call in Java

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to include SSL certificate files (.crt and .key) in HTTPS request call. But I'm getting handshake failure error while doing so. Here is my code to include the file in Java. The client expects SSL version should be TLSv1.2.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
    String uri = "https://myclient.com";
    try {
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
      keyStore.load(
          new FileInputStream(new File(
              "certificate.p12")),
          keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

      socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
          new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
              .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray()).build(),
          NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: did you correctly create a `pkcs12` compliant file with `openssl` before uploading it into the keystore?

Comment: it seems to me you did not put the `pkcs12` file into the `keystore` but you are trying to load it directy... this may be the problem

Comment: Yes, I also cross verified it by generating the key and certificate by pkcs12 file.

Comment: okok, so: is `certificate.p12` a keystore file created with `keytool`?

Comment: No, I used openssl.

Comment: I used this command : openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are trying to load a `pkcs12` file, whereas you should be loading a `keystore` file.

So the first step (which you already did) is to create a `pkcs12` (or `pfx`) file with `openssl`.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt
```

Now you have to create a `jks` compliant keystore with `java`'s [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)

```
keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore mykeystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

You will be asked a bunch of questions, including passwords.

Once you have created the keystore you can now import the `pkcs12` file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore .\mykeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

In your `Java` code you'll have to import `mykeystore.jks` instead of `certificate.p12`.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If you already have a certificate via `openssl` you don't have to start again via `keytool` with a private key. The `keytool -genkey` step is unnecessary.

Comment: @EJP you still have to generate a `keystore` if you do not have one already. I was just going through the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html) and they apply quite the same process. What's your suggestion?

Comment: @EJP it'd be nice to have some professional suggestion on that since you seem to have lots of expertise... you'd be saving me tons of work.

Comment: as i thought, you just don't know what you are talking about

Answer (score -1):

After jostling with this issue for more than a week, it has been resolved. I was trying my code on MacOS. Since Apple has deprecated use of openssl in favour of its own TLS and crypto libraries, the handshaking process gets failure with later versions of TLS.

I tried it in ubuntu and got the result.

Comment: Apple can't prevent OpenSSL from working. Answer does not make sense.